# Crop, resize and save Images with Java JAI

Tags: java, image, resize, crop, jai

I want to do the following with a folder full of images. The images are normally .jpg but it would be better being able to use any image format.

- load an image
- crop a rectangle (x, y, width, length)
- resize cropped section (finalWidth, finalLength)
- save cropped and resized section as a new image in another folder.

I am new to JAI, could somebody please explain step by step?

Thank you very much!

Comment: *"could somebody please explain step by step?"*  Don't look for a tutor at a Q&A Site.  Voting to close as 'too broad'.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. It's always nice to find people ready to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

katu, for what its worth, [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) will do all of this for you significantly easier than using JAI (single, static, method calls to perform all these ops). You can check the [class Javadoc here](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/downloads/software/imgscalr/javadoc/index.html).

You can add this Maven entry and get started with the lib immediately (no config or complex API, just call Scalr.* methods)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
    <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is better for what I want than JAI.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JAI, Checkout the jquery plugin JCrop to crop images in UI and save to your folder using simple java code.Checkout the example provided here.
http://www.javaservletsjspweb.in/2009/09/java-and-javascript-jcrop-jquery-plugin.html#.UK9XWOTqm8A